# How do I enable anonymous users to vote?

Tags: 7, polls

I created a poll, and I am displaying it in a block on my site. The radio buttons are available, when I am logged in; when I log out, they aren't showing, and the vote results are instead displayed.

How do I enable the anonymous users to vote?

Comment: looks like you need to enable the permission for anonymous users

Comment: Thank you @Bala

Which one of these is "Voting" permission?

Poll: Create new content
Poll: Edit own content
Poll: Delete own content
Poll: Delete any content

Comment: Sorry i don't think permission is not a problem, see my answer -  Drupal core poll module only allows one vote per anonymous IP address, try to view the poll page from other ip address, if it shows let me know

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you need to enable the permission for anonymous users and also

Drupal core poll module only allows one vote per anonymous IP address. check this link https://drupal.org/node/866168

The [Poll Enhancements](https://drupal.org/project/pollanon) Module modifies this behavior to allow multiple anonymous votes from the same IP address.

> This module enables anonymous users to vote on polls without page
>   cache troubles or IP address restrictions. It is designed to work on
>   top of core Poll module.

Comment: Thanks @Bala
I have never voted, so why is it not allowing me to vote for the first time? :(

Comment: Sorry to bother you @Bala - does it make sense that it is not letting me vote (for the first time)? There are 0 votes so far.

Comment: @kine456 better you try Poll Enhancements Module to avoid this type of issues

Comment: WOw. I feel so silly. I just had to scroll down to the "Vote on polls" section and enable the right permissions.

Comment: @kine456 Hmmm i doubt the same, that's why i mentioned in the first comment, good to go.